# Is it possible to read a file and to storage the buffer directly into shared memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, system-calls

Actually, I'm coding a C application on Linux that has to read from a file descriptor and then to storage the read buffer into shared memory between processes.

I've tried this:

```
while(1) {
        if(read (chRPMSG, data_buff[data_buff_it], SIZE_MSG) < 0) exit(0);
        else {
            data_buff_it = (data_buff_it + 1) % NUM_ELEMENTS;
        }
    }
```

where `data_buff_it` is defined as `char **data_buff;` and initialized as `data_buff = mmap(NULL, NUM_ELEMENTS * SIZE_MSG, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);`.

This code would be perfect for my purpose. However, it doesn't work since appears next error `14 EFAULT Bad address`.

I know that there are a lot of different ways to solve the problem, but for example copying the read buffer whit `strcpy` to `data_buff` isn't working due to the fact that system call is too slow for reading frequency (1024 Hz, 448 bytes per message) - note that I'm working whit a microprocessor.

Is there any other way to write directly into shared memory? If not, any ideas to enhance `strcpy`'s delay?

Comment: Check [boost interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_named_interprocess) More likely your linux distribution already have boot installed, if not most of the distributions allow you to install it using package manger. I think you will interested in stroing some [vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) in the shared memory, and you can fill this vector from a file.

Comment: Try `vmsplice`, I think.

Comment: You should post more code, especially definitions of data_buff and data_buff_it. The amount of code should be sufficient to compile and run the program and generate the error you have mentioned.